# Display a QLabel at the top-centre of the window

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm having trouble setting up PyQt on my own. My idea its to creat a music-player with a song title and album cover. I have had success in creating my own window and adding the album cover. But I can't add the label in the right position. I want the song title to be at the top-center of the window, like the image below:

[image]

I have tried a lot of ways, but had no luck.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect

# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 480
        self.height = 320
        self.initUI()

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

    def add_font(self):
        # Load the font:
        font_db = QFontDatabase()
        font_id = font_db.addApplicationFont('American Captain.ttf')
        families = font_db.applicationFontFamilies(font_id)
        ttf_font = QFont(' '.join(families), 15)
        return ttf_font

    def initUI(self):
        ttf_font = self.add_font()
        w = QWidget()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()
        album_cover = QLabel(self)
        album_pic = QPixmap('resized_image.jpg')
        album_cover.setPixmap(album_pic)

        album_cover.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(album_cover)


        art_alb = QLabel(self)
        art_alb.setFont(ttf_font)
        art_alb.setText("michael buble - christmas")
        art_alb.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y)
        art_alb.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignCenter )
        art_alb.show()
        self.show()



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a central widget with a layout to control how the child widgets are sized and positioned in the main window. Here is a re-write of your `initUI` method that should do what you want:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(widget)

        art_alb = QLabel(self)
        ttf_font = self.add_font()
        art_alb.setFont(ttf_font)
        art_alb.setText("michael buble - christmas")

        layout.addWidget(art_alb, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignHCenter)

        album_cover = QLabel(self)
        album_pic = QPixmap('image.jpg')
        album_cover.setPixmap(album_pic)

        layout.addWidget(album_cover, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Note that there's no need to keep calling `show()`, since this is all handled automatically by the layout. For more information, see the [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) article in the Qt docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everythings work perfectly, but if i want to add another text under "art_alb" at the same center what i should add more in my code.    Thanks

Comment: @BarryAllen Do the same as for the first label, but add it to row `1` when calling `addWidget`. This means you will also need to change the row to `2` when adding `album_cover`. (The first number is the row, the second number is the column).